# Как узнать размер окна приложения (В том числе и полноэкранного) в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Предположим, **я хочу найти размер окна** приложения (Не python!).

Как я могу это сделать, и **отличается ли способ нахождения окна, от нахождения размера полноэкранного приложения?**

*p.s. **гугл прям совсем пустой**, выдаёт только "как узнать размер окна tkinter'а"*

Comment: какой вы модуль используете? pygame или что то еще?

Comment: @alex9127, я не использую модули, вообще, сейчас речь идёт не о нахождение размера окна самого приложения - Python, а другого, например того же открытого блокнота.

Comment: а, вот так? честно не знаю

Comment: уточните вопрос пожалуйста

Comment: @alex9127 ну вот и я, задался таким вопросом, просто гугл не так меня понимает, и выдаёт совсем не то.

Comment: В linux в shell (из командной строки) `echo $LINES $COLUMNS` (остается вызвать из python и прочесть в  2 переменные stdout)

Comment: @avp спасибо, но у меня Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете получить координаты окна, используя функцию GetWindowRect. Для этого вам понадобится дескриптор окна, который вы можете получить с помощью FindWindow, если вы знаете что-то об окне (например, его заголовок).
Предполагая, что вы работаете в Windows, попробуйте использовать модуль pywin32 win32gui с его функциями EnumWindows и GetWindowRect.
Если вы используете Mac OS X, вы можете попробовать использовать appscript.
Для Linux вы можете попробовать один из множества интерфейсов к X11.

```
import win32gui

def callback(hwnd, extra):
    rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    x = rect[0]
    y = rect[1]
    w = rect[2] - x
    h = rect[3] - y
    print("Window %s:" % win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
    print("\tLocation: (%d, %d)" % (x, y))
    print("\t    Size: (%d, %d)" % (w, h))

def main():
    win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**UPDATE** Конкретно для блокнота:

```
import win32gui

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow("notepad", None)
rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
w = rect[2] - rect[0]
h = rect[3] - rect[1]
print("Window %s:" % win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
print("\t    Size: (%d, %d)" % (w, h))
```

Comment: Как можно посмотреть размеры отдельного процесса? Одного.
Например: Блокнота?

Comment: `hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Блокнот")  rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)  width = rect[2] - rect[0] height = rect[3] - rect[1]`

Comment: @userpy Обновил ответ с правильным кодом конкретно под ваш запрос. Если ответ вас устраивает, то примите его нажав на галочку